# Save Prompt While download from IE using vba

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I am going to download file from secure website.
Its everytime asking while saving.

is there any way to download file from attached webpage

[image]

Suggest me to download file to specific path without prompt

File Link is "https://www.connect2nse.com/ENIT/imsscsv_download.jsp?filename=07730_Dormant_Account_08022019.csv&filepath=/dmsapp/mnt/appln/DMSWeblogic/ENIT_FILES/COMMUNICATION_LOG/SENDER/INVESTIGATION_ALERTS/07730_Dormant_Account_08022019.csv"

```
<a href="/ENIT/imsscsv_download.jsp?filename=07730_Dormant_Account_08022019.csv&amp;filepath=/dmsapp/mnt/appln/DMSWeblogic/ENIT_FILES/COMMUNICATION_LOG/SENDER/INVESTIGATION_ALERTS/07730_Dormant_Account_08022019.csv">
                     07730_Dormant_Account_08022019.csv</a>
```

I am also not able to download file from above mentioned weblink

but using right click, system directly allow file to save

is there any other option using vba to save file without prompt by click is href link

kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

When it's about downloading files, it is better to use `XmlHttpRequest` instead of robotic web scraping. 
With the below macro:

```
Sub DownloadFile(ByVal fileLink As String, ByVal username, ByVal password)

    Dim XmlHttpReq As Object
    Set XmlHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    XmlHttpReq.Open "GET", fileLink, False, username, password
    XmlHttpReq.send '<-- send the GET request of your resource file to the website

    fileLink = XmlHttpReq.responseBody 'save response body
    If XmlHttpReq.Status = 200 Then 'if GET request was OK
        Set adodbStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 'Create a Stream
        adodbStream.Open 'open it
        adodbStream.Type = 1 
        adodbStream.Write XmlHttpReq.responseBody 'write response in it
        adodbStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.csv", 2 ' 1 = doesn't overwrite, 2 = overwrites 'save it
        adodbStream.Close 'close stream
    End If

End Sub
```

... you should be able to perform your save as such:

```
Sub YourMainMacro()
    '... your code
    DownloadFile yourAHRef, yourUsername, yourPassword
    '...continue your code
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ashish set a breakpoint on the line `fileLink = XmlHttpReq.responseBody` and add a watch to `XmlHttpReq`. See if the object is correctly set.